# difference between adding resolvers in builds.sbt vs plugins.sbt

Tags: playframework-2.6

I suppose I can add `resolvers` in either `build.sbt` or `project/plugins.sbt`. Is there a difference if I pick one over the other

Eg

```
resolvers += "Atlassian Releases" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/content/public/"
```